# How to temporarily freeze entire display from within WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, screen, freeze

I'm looking for a way - probably win32 API - to freeze the entire display from within my .Net WPF application.

Reason: Well, this time it's not to annoy users. I basically want to hide some background file operations, who are opening File Save Dialog boxes. Applying the file name is being handled by my app, by simulating keystrokes.

Comment: `System.Thread.Sleep` :) Seriously, if I have a frozen application, I can't avoid killing it as I think it's broken. And why wouldn't user filedialog with no user interaction. This is no more a dialog in this case!

Comment: Why the heck, would you use some dialogs if you want to handle programmatically the file op? Ô_o

Comment: I think he wants to freeze the *entire* display, not just his program.

Comment: If you need to freeze the entire display, then you are probably doing it wrong. If your file operations are being done programmatically, then you shouldn't need to open file save dialogs and simulate keystrokes, you should be able to skip that whole part. If you just want to temporarily prevent user interaction while your program does something, then the property you are looking for is called "IsEnabled". Set it at the Window level and it should cascade down to the child controls unless they have something else setting their IsEnable.

Comment: If @MattBurland is right, take a look at the busy box control

Comment: "Well, this time it's not to annoy users". Does it mean another time it **was** to annoy user? :D

Comment: @SteveB: Just a note in case the OP is unaware, Thread.Sleep would also stop the file operations the OP wants to do unless they are running on a separate thread.

Comment: I think that the File Save Dialog boxes are coming from another application. Need more info.

Comment: This sounds like a terribly-designed program already and here you are trying to make it **even more horrible**. Simulating keystrokes is *not* the way you deal with dialog boxes; that's so incredibly fragile and subject to error that it causes me physical pain. Freezing the entire screen is *not* an acceptable solution; Windows is a multiple application operating system and you are not the only thing that the user has running or that they might be doing. This is a pile of cards, just waiting to fall down at the next strong gust of wind, and a hurricane is on the horizon. **Find another way.**

Comment: @SteveB: I agree with Matt Burland. Also, Thread.Sleep will not stop other windows from painting.

Comment: And to everyone wondering why when saving programatically I need to mess with dialog boxes and keystrokes, here is the answer: I have a certain application printing to a file. It cannot be printed via a standard printer driver. It is that particular application only that can handle the printing. I get access to that application via OLE in order to instruct it to print. However, I cannot supply a file path as a parameter. What happens is, the file save dialog appears.  And with regards to the annoyance, (Thanks everybody for the concern) it is a matter of split seconds.

Comment: A split second is still enough time to cause a serious problem. Besides, not everyone's computer is as fast as your development machine. And people might be running multiple applications in the background. There are all sorts of *serious* problems with this proposal, beyond the fact that you simply cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

As all the comments are pointing out, this is maybe a terrible design, but you need an answer anyway.

I have done something similar in the past by taking a screenshot and placing it on a window without borders nor title, that uses all the space and is above all other windows.

Comment: Many thanks. I came across already such a suggestion. I wanted to see first if there are any quicker and easier ways to accomplish that.

Comment: What happens when I click one of the items in that screenshot? Or press a key on the keyboard? And if you have a top-level window with the focus that is receiving keyboard events, how is he doing to synthesize keyboard input that dismisses the dialog shown by a different window? Windows without the focus do not receive keyboard events.